# Why the function $y=\frac{1}{x}$ with $x\neq 0$ is NOT a solution of the differential equation $y' + y^2 =0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

Why the function $y=\frac{1}{x}$  with $x\neq 0$  is NOT  a solution of the differential equation $y' + y^2 =0$

I did it, but for me it should be the solution.

$\frac{dy}{dx} = -x^{-2}$

$y' + y^2= -x^{-2} + \frac{1}{x^2} = 0$

So where is the error and why is $y(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ not a solution.

Comment: Welcome on math.SE! See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a guide on how to typeset equation correctly.

Comment: Why are you saying it is not a solution? It over $\mathbb{R}^{+*}$ or $\mathbb{R}^{-*}$ (but not unique).

Answer (score 2):

$$ y= \frac {1}{x}$$ is just one particular solution not the general solution.

The general solution is $$y=\frac {1}{x-c}$$ where c is an arbitrary constant.

If an initial value is given then you can find the constant c.

For example if $y(0)=3$, then $$ c= \frac {-1}{3}$$ which results in $$ y=\frac {3}{x+1} $$